# Persistant CPLEX - module cplex has no attribute cplex

Tags: python, cplex, pyomo

I am currently creating a model in pyomo and using cplex as a solver(persistant cplex) to be specific which uses the python API.

I tried running this on my local windows machine and after installing setup.py it work. However, when i switch to run this on my linux server, I keep getting the error "Module cplex has no attribute CPLEX". It is also asking to checking if I have gotten my python bindings right.

CPLEX : v12.10
Python : v3.6 (64 bit)

I have tried creating virtual environments and adding the original cplex installation location(/opt/...) to my PATH but to no avail.

Let me know if you need any additioanl information and any help would be apprecaited

Answer (score 0):

Windows depends on a package manager that handles programs that end in
.exe
As for open source Linux systems, they depend on Debian's package manager, which means that you cannot run the Windows program on Linux and vice versa, so check with the systems' package manager

Comment: I used the x64 linux installation and the setup.py found inside that installation location